# How do I combine the error when multiplying a number by a proportion

Tags: variance, standard-error, error

I wish to know how many seals are in an area. Seals have been counted in a portion of the area, once each month over multiple years. Separately, several seals in the area have been fitted with GPS tracking devices and the proportion of time they were available to be counted in the surveyed portion of the area has been determined.

e.g., Counts for July: (102, 192, 85, 90, 80, 102, 83) n = 7 counts, mean = 105, SD = 39.4

Proportions of time tracked seals spent in the surveyed portion: (0.51, 0.62, 0.20, 0.44, 0.72, 0.52) n = 6 seals, mean = 0.50, SD = 0.18

Estimate of total seals = 105/0.50 = 210

But what is the error on that estimate (SD, SE or Variance)?

Comment: This isn't my field at all. But I see very large uncertainty here. The observed range of seals is itself very wide, [80, 192]. Furthermore, you are trying to infer (by extrapolation) the population from the proportion of time spent in an area by 6 seals. 6 seals out of (what we know can be up to) 192 is very small.

Answer (score 1):

It's called fractional uncertainty, and for a product or ratio like

\begin{equation}
q=\frac{x \times \cdots \times z}{u \times \cdots \times w},
\end{equation}
the fractional uncertainty of $q$ is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sigma_q}{|q|}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\sigma_x}{x}\right)^2 + \cdots + \left(\frac{\sigma_z}{z}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sigma_u}{u}\right)^2 + \cdots + \left(\frac{\sigma_w}{w}\right)^2}.
\end{equation}
Thus, the s.d. of $q$ is (after rearranging)
\begin{equation}
\sigma_q=|q|\sqrt{\left(\frac{\sigma_x}{x}\right)^2 + \cdots + \left(\frac{\sigma_z}{z}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sigma_u}{u}\right)^2 + \cdots + \left(\frac{\sigma_w}{w}\right)^2}.
\end{equation}

So, for your estimated ratio (105/0.5), the s.d. is
\begin{equation}
\sigma=210 \sqrt{\left(\frac{39.4}{105}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{0.18}{0.5}\right)^2 }
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks, but that gives an SD on 210 seals of 0.5, which doesn't seem reasonable?

Comment: Apologies, the $\sigma$ needs to be multiplied by the absolute value of the ratio (in case it's negative). See modified answer.